# Parsing from a Facebook page with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, parsing

I'd like to know whether it is possible to take (within PHP) informations of some users who have liked a Facebook page saved locally.

Francesca Varano (Vari) Roma È fan di Rock 'n' Shot, ARTRIBUNE e altri 1128.

Sorry for the formatting, there are many users in the page and I don't know how to get the information without knowing the class or div id. If anyone has any idea, I would be very grateful.

Comment: English only on this site.

Comment: Translated as much as I can. Please review the translation and modify where you feel it's needed